# I put my hopes and dreams too high?

Tags: grammar

I'd like to know whether this sentence is correct or not: 
"I put my hopes and dreams too high."

Or are there any alternative phrases saying that someone expected more and therefore he/she is disappointed.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

sounds good but I would write - I set my hopes and dreams too high.

Comment: 'Set' sounds better than 'put'. You might consider 'raised' as an alternative.